# Chrome Extension: How do I get current tabs title and assign string to variable?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to get the title of the current tab in chrome using an extension and then assigning the returned string to a variable. I managed to get the title using `tabs[0].title` but I haven't been able to assign that title to a new string variable.

This is the code:

```
var address;

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    var title = tab.title;

    console.log("Title: " + title);
    address = title;
});

console.log("Address:" + address);
```

The line `console.log("Title: " + title);` shows that `tab.title` is working as expected, however, when I try to assign the title string to a new variable (`address`) it is not working shown when the line `console.log("Address:" + address);` returns `"Address:Undefined"`.

I have also tried creating the variable `address` as an empty string in the first line. This looks like: `var address = new String();`

I have looked on here and looked at the documentation and couldn't find an answer to the problem I am having.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to use a callback function. See below the example.

```
var address;

chrome.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true}, function(tabs) {
    var tab = tabs[0];
    var title = tab.title;

    console.log("Title: " + title);
    address = title;
    print_address(address);
});

function print_address(address) {
    console.log("Address:" + address);
}
```